# CorDapp Suite and Dependencies

Tags: corda

Let's say I want to use a cash-based CorDapp for DVP with my CP Trading CorDapp (But I do not want to be responsible for updating/developing cash). How does one note CorDapp dependencies for deployment? What if the cash CorDapp updates their state or contract definition?

If cash is too specific, let's say I want to use an API that reaches out to another data source for enrichment or validation of my state. Does this have to be an Oracle? Can we implement this API call as a CorDapp that's installed in a CorDapp Suite so it stays decentralized or must it contain a signature of an oracle in order to keep the transaction valid?

Answer (score 1):

You specify the dependencies of your CorDapp in the `dependencies` section of your build.gradle file. For example, the following line would include the `corda-finance` module, which includes cash:

`cordapp "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"`

As you can see, you specify the version of the CorDapp that you wish to use.

By default, when you build a CorDapp, the CorDapp jar's name is determined by:

- The name of the module where the sources are defined
- The `version` property in a project's gradle.properties file

So if the version number is `0.1`, and your module is called `clemens-dvp`, building the CorDapp jar will create a file called `clemens-dvp-0.1.jar`.

See further information here: https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html. The docs state:

"The filename of the jar must include some sort of unique identifier to deduplicate it from other releases of the same CorDapp. This is typically done by appending the version string. It should not change once the jar has been deployed on a node."